# Microsoft Publisher doesn't draw work area

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-publisher

I'm trying to open a file in Microsoft Publisher and everything seems to work, except that the work area (I dont know it's proper name, but where the pages are) doesn't seem to draw properly.

It just stays whatever the application behind it was showing on screen in that area and doesnt seem to respond to clicks in that area.

The ribbon and sidebars appear to still function, indeed, inserting items shows them in the preview on the left pane.

What I have tried so far: Restarting computer, 
closing all publisher windows and making sure all publisher processes are killed and then reopening, 
Opening the program and creating a new file (still does the same thing), opening the program and then using the file open to open the document. Opening document on another computer works just fine.

Thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps try updating your graphics chipset drivers. Also you could try the Office installer's Repair option in the Programs and Features part of the Control Panel.

Comment: I'll try both of these first thing in the morning. I would have tried the office one this afternoon, but the teacher needed her computer >.> _sarcasm_ ugh, It's not like they have work to do or anything _sarcasm_

Comment: Graphics card did nothing, but reinstalling office fixed it. Submit me an answer @James ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try updating your graphics chipset drivers in case there is a bug causing incompatibility with Office.

You could also try the Office installer's **Repair** option in case Publisher has somehow got corrupted:

- Go to **Control Panel->Programs and Features**.
- Right-click the entry for Office 2010
- Click **Change**.
- Click **Repair->Continue**

Comment: Office repair fixed it for me!